# Foundation imports with Libsass, node-sass-middleware not compiling

Tags: node.js, express, zurb-foundation, node-sass

I am using Node.js with Express as my base for my app, and am attempting to use the npm packages *node-sass-middleware* for sass compilation and *foundation-sites* for the foundation scss source.

My app.js contains the following,

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');

app.use(sassMiddleware({
src: path.join(__dirname,'scss'),
dest: path.join(__dirname,'public/css'),
prefix: '/css',
includePaths:[path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/')], //Make sure we include the foundation library. ^-^;
debug: true,
outputStyle: 'extended'

}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

My style.scss looks like:

```
@import 'foundation';

@import 'stuff'; /*Testing imports functionality*/

body{

    color:black; /*Just for testing compilation*/

}
```

and stuff.scss looks like:

```
somerandomtag{

    @extend body;
    border:5px solid black;

}
```

In my layout.jade I've added

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
```

When I refresh my page, in my log I can see the following output:

> GET /login 200 356.910 ms - 511   source:
>   F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\scss\style.scss   dest:
>   F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\public\css\style.css
>   read: F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\public\css\style.css
>   GET /js/jquery.cookie.js 304 7.621 ms - - GET /css/style.css - - ms -
>   -   render: F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\scss\style.scss   source:
>   F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\scss\style.scss   dest:
>   F:\Users\trutt\Documents\Projects\MyProject\public\css\style.css GET
>   /css/style.css 200 7.127 ms - 269

All finally resulting in the compiled style.css:

```
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.2.1
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
somerandomtag {
  border: 5px solid black; }

/*Testing imports functionality*/
body, somerandomtag {
  color: black;
  /*Just for testing compilation*/ }
```

The header for foundation itself is visible, which tells me my include path is working. I have proven that Sass seems to be working via compilation checks and import tests, as well as inheritance. But... where is all of foundations css rules? Have I missed something?

All of the packages installed were freshly installed within the last 24 hours directly from npm so I would assume I'm working with the latest npm package versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of playing with different sass/gulp/gem alternatives, I found my issue.

I was exploring the files included with foundation-sites included in the npm package.

It seems changing the following like in app.js

```
includePaths:[path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/')],
```

To

```
includePaths:[path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/')],
```

Fixed the issues.

I believe this is because the file foundation.scss in the above assets path contains

```
@import '../scss/foundation';

@include foundation-everything;
```

I assume the bottom line is what makes the difference. Likely the other files in the /scss/ folder do not include foundation-everything. Which I assume is the master include for the compiled foundation css.

Again, built off assumptions as to why and how this works, but documentation on Foundation with node-sass-middleware via NPM on Express is scarce, and this issue is resolved with the above modification.

Comment: I encountered this same problem too.The reason your solution works is because if you follow the `@import` statements, you'll see that everything you're importing is wrapped in mixins. If you include `[foundation]/scss/foundation.scss` yourself, the mixins are declared, but not actually used. That `@include foundation-everything` is a mix-in that ends up including all those mixins. (I'd be curious if there is an advantage to designing Foundation this way)

Comment: Now that I think about this, I see that the advantage. If you `@import [foundation]/scss/foundation`, you get access to all the mixins in your project, so you can include components (or even parts of components) using `@include` statements. That gives you a lot of control so that you're only building the parts you need, instead of importing at the file-level.